# Python/Matplotlib -> to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, contour

I'm trying to plot contours and have previously used a RGB tuple to specify the color (only one for all contours) - however, now I get a ValueError from to_rgba:

```
ValueError: to_rgba: Invalid rgba arg "1"
to_rgb: Invalid rgb arg "1"
cannot convert argument to rgb sequence
```

Here is an example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
grid = np.random.random((10,10))
contours = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
```

Now this works!

```
plt.contour(grid, levels = contours, colors = 'r')
plt.show()
```

But this does NOT work!

```
plt.contour(grid, levels = contours, colors = (1,0,0))
plt.show()
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this bug (/new feature) in Matplotlib? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't that what you would expect? `colors` takes a sequence of colors. In your case it tries to interpret `1`, not (1,0,0) , as a rgb color. `colors="#ff0000"` appears to work as expected.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments, `plt.contour()` expects a sequence of colors. If you want to specify an RGB tuple, make it the first element of such a sequence.

```
plt.contour(grid, levels = contours, colors = ((1,0,0),) )
```

or

```
plt.contour(grid, levels = contours, colors = [(1,0,0),] )
```